# CruiseControl.NET & web interface customization

Tags: c#, .net, build-process, cruisecontrol.net, build-automation

everybody!

I'm really puzzled with my build server improvements.
The point is that we have a specific build process in our company. On the one hand, it's quite simple:

- Update source code from SVN
- Build VisualStudio solution (C++ & C#)
- Build distributives
- Move distributives to specific server folder

On the other hand, we have about 200 different distributives of one project. We don't want to do build of all of them every day, but during a day some people need to build some distributives. Initially we had a cmd file to build the project. Then, I wrote the simple web-interface to generate cmd files and organize a build queue. This solution is acceptable, but
its maintanence is becoming really painful as project grows.

Now I have a choice - use CruiseControl.NET (or something like that) or improve my own program. What I really need is:

1. Web-interface where user can choose distributive and some build params
2. Web-interface with some statistics (builds, that were made, current revision of repository, current revision of working copy etc)
3. Flexible config to customize build process

As far as I know, I can get (2) and (3) out of box with CruiseControl.NET, but what about (1)? Also, I'm not sure, that use CI-server, when I actually don't need CI, is a good decision.

**So, here is my question:** is it a good decision to use CC.NET or should I improve my own program?

P.S. I've read [this article](http://file:///C:/Program%20Files%20%28x86%29/CruiseControl.NET/webdashboard/doc/CCNET/Developing%20Web%20Dashboard%20Plugins.html), but I'm still not sure about CC.NET web interface opportunities...

Answer (score 0):

You can always have a mixed mode : **Your own small applciation** serving a CC.NET or HUDSON intergation tasks.

It is not so easy to change the gui of these tools, beyond the look and feel modification.

Answer (score 0):

We achieve #1 with ccnet by creating a cc project for each value of a certain "parameter" that is needed.

We started out with an incremental build and a full build in ccnet.

The incremental build updated a working copy, built it, ran a partial set of unittests and emailed the results.

The full build updated a different working copy, rebuilt the solution, ran all the unittests, generated installers, exported the installers to certain places and finally triggered regression tests on other designated test machines.

The full build did a lot of stuff and sometimes we only wanted to rebuild the code and generate the installers. We wanted to avoid having to run the unittests and spawn the regression tests.

So we added another cc project called fullbuild_notest. This executes the same nant targets as the fullbuild except it skips the testing part. We have a nant build file that's sort of a bootstrapper with entry points. At the beginning we set a property named "fullbuild-testing-enabled" to true or false and then call a child target to do the actual building. The child target and its children check the "fullbuild-testing-enabled" flag to determine whether or not to do testing.

In a way this is good because it gives the dashboard users a certain set of choices. And in a way it's cumbersome because every time a new parameter or parameter value is needed, a change to the nant/ccnet code is required.